# Python matrix in matrix in matrix

Tags: python

In my program I use this var:

```
payoff_matrix = [ [(4,4),(1,6)] , [(6,1),(2,2)] ]
```

And i need to check (4,4) and (2,2), (It can be anything)
I use

```
  a=payoff_matrix[0]
  b=a[0]
  c=b[0]
  d=b[1]
```

And result is

```
  c=4
  d=4
```

Can I go to that like

```
c=payoff_matrix[0].[0].[0]
```

or somehow?

Comment: are you trying to find out the index of `(4,4)` and `(2,2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [4]: mat = [ [(4,4),(1,6)] , [(6,1),(2,2)] ]

In [6]: c,d=mat[0][0]    #here mat[0] is [(4,4),(1,6)], invoking [0] on this yields [4,4]

In [7]: c
Out[7]: 4

In [8]: d
Out[8]: 4


In [9]: a,b=mat[1][1]  #here mat[1] is [(6,1),(2,2)], invoking [1] on this yields [2,2]

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 2

In [11]: b
Out[11]: 2
```